# Display all meta for a post?

Tags: php, post-meta

I have a custom meta field for my posts and I'm able to display the value. But it only displays one row. Since I have more than one value I need to display all of them. I know I probably have to do some kind of for or while loop, but I don't know how to do it.

This is my current code:

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-text', true );

if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) :
    echo $meta_value; 
endif;
```

How do I change that snippet to display all rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get all rows, don't specify the key. Try this:

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );

var_dump( $meta_values );  // so you can see the structure
```

Comment: It works, but is there no way to get an array by key? I can work with this, just wondering.

Comment: You mean you want all values for a key in the post_meta table, regardless of post_id? If so, look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column

Comment: No, only for the current post. But there are usually more than one result with that key. Anyway I made it work thanks to your answer, just thought it would look better in the code if it was possible to get them all by key.